# Oracle SQL Developer - "IO Error: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"

Tags: sql, oracle, connection, runtime

I am trying to run a query overnight and it never gets to run to completion because of the above error message. Does anyone know any simple solutions or settings that I can alter in Oracle SQL developer so that the connection stays open.

Comment: It sounds like an OS-level problem, or maybe security software like McAfee, probably seeing this as an "idle" connection and hitting a timeout. Since each worksheet or tool within SQL Developer generally establishes its own connection, I'm not sure there's any way to avoid that happening.

Comment: what have you tried so far?